# how to solve (__bridge CFURLRef) so it compiles with xcode 3.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, compatibility

I try to get some code to work which is coded with xcode 4.1. My target system is osx 10.5 with Xcode 3.1. So while compiling often some property issues come up, which i'm able to handle. But the following code, i don't know how to solve clever.

The compiler said: **`'__bridge'` undeclared (first use in this function)**

*A) I know this is a macro, but want to know if i can just erase that phrase* `(__bridge CFURLRef)`*?

B) is there a more clever solution, i have to learn?

C) knowledge: what for is this* `__bridge` *exactly, between what it is a bridge?*

```
static BOOL willStartAtLogin() {
    NSURL *appurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    BOOL found = NO;
    LSSharedFileListRef items = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
    if (items) {
        UInt32 seed;
        CFArrayRef itemsArray = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(items, &seed);
        CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(itemsArray);
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            LSSharedFileListItemRef a = (LSSharedFileListItemRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(itemsArray, i);
            CFURLRef url = NULL;
            OSStatus err = LSSharedFileListItemResolve(a, kLSSharedFileListNoUserInteraction | kLSSharedFileListDoNotMountVolumes, &url, NULL);
            if (err == noErr) {
                // here follows the problematic part
                found = CFEqual(url, (__bridge CFURLRef)appurl);
                CFRelease(url);
                if (found) { break; }
            }
        }
        CFRelease(items);
    }
    return found;
}
```

**EDIT**
After @Catfish_Man 's answer, id like to know how this code would look like without ARC, even it would be a hard work to implement all the missing memory management in this modern code!

**EDIT2**
with a little search i found out there is a library which solves backward compatibility for compiling code on modern systems for older OS without ARC. seen here: https://github.com/plausiblelabs/PLWeakCompatibility
Is there something equivalent which can help someone compiling such code on older 32bit OS?

Answer (score 0):

This code is using Automatic Reference Counting. You will need to rewrite all memory management in the entire codebase, and turn off ARC, to target older OSs.

Comment: hmm, indeed would be lot to do. but i just can learn with it.

Comment: maybe stupid question, but how would the code above look like without ARC. change the return value to `return [found autorelease]`?

Comment: You can't autorelease primitives, so it would look the same.